# How to access FAT32 HDD in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fat32

I have this FAT32 HDD that I would like to access but everytime I get this error message:

> Unable to Access "Windows C:"
>
> The drive is either corrupted, inaccessable or uses an unsupported file system.

I am currently using debian. When I load a portable hard drive formatted with FAT32, It loads fine. I only get this error with internal FAT32 hard drives. I swapped it out for a NTFS and it worked accessed it, when I put the FAT32 hard drive back in, it gave the exact same error message as before. Debain crashes whenever I try to access it after manually mounting the drive.

Comment: Are you sure it is not something wrong with the hard drive? Does it check out S.M.A.R.T.-wise ?

Comment: I checked it and it turned out positive, meaning no errors. Also, gpart showed no corrupted partitions in the HDD.

Comment: have you tried to manually mount it?

Comment: Yes. I tried to manually mount it. It mounted without any error but Debian crashes whenever I try to access it. I am using Debian Stable.

Comment: hmm. Try to further isolate it. Do you have another machine you can try it in? Or perhaps burn a Live DVD and try it with another OS?

Comment: guess fsck will not run?

Comment: Got that right. Fsck outright refuses to run on that HDD. Also, to answer the other question, the only other machine I have is a Surface Pro 3. And the Surface Pro 3 only supports SSDs not HDDs.

Comment: A crash of Debian for an attempt to access is rather unusual. It seems an hardware problem. Can you mount the HDD in a USB box and try it? This because if it is an hardware problem it shouldn't block you system and you should be able to read the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the logs(`/var/log/syslog` I think) to understand why your debian is crashing on mounting.

I think you must try first to connect it, but not manually mounting. Look to dmesg (`sudo dmesg`)last messages because debian will try to automount it, and could be failing.

Then run a `sudo fdisk -l` to know which is you device on `/dev` and then execute a `sudo fsck /dev/sdX`.

That should give you some info.

Comment: Using your advice, I managed to fix it. It according to the logs, after some searching, that the FAT32 partition was 'locked' and couldn't be accessed from an external system I unlocked the partition and was able to access it without debain crashing on me.